Question about the heaven
What is meant by the sky being built or a building? For example in these next two verses Quran 2:22 and Quran 40:64 the word بِنَآءًۭ is used which i think means building.
Quran 40:64

"It is Allāh who made for you the earth a place of settlement and the sky a structure [i.e., ceiling] and formed you and perfected your forms and provided you with good things. That is Allāh, your Lord; then blessed is Allāh, Lord of the worlds."

and Quran 2:22

"[He] who made for you the earth a bed [spread out] and the sky a ceiling and sent down from the sky, rain and brought forth thereby fruits as provision for you. So do not attribute to Allāh equals while you know [that there is nothing similar to Him]."

and in Quran 50:6 the word used is بَنَيْنَـٰهَا which means built i think

"Have they not looked at the heaven above them - how We structured it and adorned it and [how] it has no rifts?"


We have propped up, constructed etc.
Like when we say the cosmos is a celestial structure.
The language is used in a way that Arabs would relate to, it obviously is not going to say we gravitationally are maintaining the mass in space.

i was wondering what would be meant by the heavens being created without pillars? Quran 31:10 im asking because arent they skies

@user65094 The ancients used to believe the heavens required invisible pillars, the Quran states there are no need for such pillars, its all upheld by God.
